# Keyboard not visible

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager

My application has a ViewPager and dynamic WebView. When the page displays the captcha (anti-bot) to enter, then when you click on the component input, the keyboard is not displayed. When I removed the ViewPager and left just a WebView - keyboard is displayed. In what may be the problem?

```
adapter=new BrowserPagerAdapter(pages);
    viewpager=new ViewPager(this);
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
    setContentView(viewpager);
```

Comment: Check whether the editable text userInteraction is enabled

Comment: How can I verify this? My problem is that ViewPager as it blocks the keyboard display.